# Jsoup: looping through table rows

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to parse this document: https://www.worldfootball.net/teams/liverpool-fc/1982/2/
I selected the main table from which I would like to extract text from the rows, e.g. the Goalkeeper from

```
<th colspan="7" class="gross"><b>Goalkeeper</b></th>
```

and from the next rows name and country like

```
<a href="/player_summary/bruce-grobbelaar/" title="Bruce Grobbelaar">Bruce Grobbelaar</a>

<td class="hell">Zimbabwe</td>
```

Can I loop through all the rows and check if there is a colspan to extract Goalkeeper, Defender, etc. or other text?

Answer (score 0):

After you have parsed your response with JSoup you can call `.getElementsByTag("th")` to get all th-enclosed elements as array. The array you can loop normally and get the Goalkeeper, etc value through i.e. `element.getElementsByTag("b").ownText()`.